# Find the shortest rectangular range that contains another range

Tags: vb.net, excel, range, add-in

Let's suppose that I have the following range:

```
$A$2:$C$3,$D$4:$E$5,$G$7
```

There is some combination of methods that gives me the shortest rectangular range that contains this one? In my example, the answer should be:

```
$A$2:$G$7
```

OBS: I'm building an add-in for Excel 2013 using VSTO 2013 with VB.NET

Thank you!

Comment: There are infinite rectangular ranges that contains any target range. When I say "shortest" I mean the one with the smallest area and still contains the target range...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the `.Areas` of the non-contiguous ranges.

```
Dim a, r1 As Long, c1 As Long, r2 As Long, c2 As Long, rng As Range
Range("$A$2:$C$3,$D$4:$E$5,$G$7").Select
Range("$A$2:$G$7").Select
r1 = Rows.Count: r2 = 1
c1 = Columns.Count: c2 = 1
With Range("$A$2:$C$3,$D$4:$E$5,$G$7")
    For Each rng In .Areas
        With rng
            If .Cells(1, 1).Row < r1 Then r1 = .Cells(1, 1).Row
            If .Cells(1, 1).Column < c1 Then c1 = .Cells(1, 1).Column
            If .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Row > r2 Then r2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Row
            If .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Column > c2 Then c2 = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).Column
        End With
    Next rng
End With
Debug.Print Range(Cells(r1, c1), Cells(r2, c2)).Address(0, 0)
```

I'm not completely sure how that is going to fit into a VB.Net/VSTO project but that is how the problem would be approached in VBA. The methods should be easily transferrable to an Excel object in VB.Net.

Comment: @LeonardoValverde - TBH there is probably a better way to do this but when I'm in a hurry I prefer the brick-by-brick approach.